# Please help me with this Sage install error caused by PHP 8.0.2

Tags: php, wordpress, roots-sage

So I'm trying to install a basic Sage theme, but I keep getting this error:

[click here for the error or read below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrJ6K.png)

PHP 8.0.2 causes some problems and I am stuck with finding a solution...

Can somebody give me some tips on what I should do?

error:

```
$ composer create-project roots/sage my-first-sage-theme
Creating a "roots/sage" project at "./my-first-sage-theme"
Installing roots/sage (9.0.10)
  - Installing roots/sage (9.0.10): Extracting archive
Created project in D:\FUN\My-First-Sage-Website\wp-content\themes\my-first-sage-theme
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)    
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/config is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/config v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.   
  Problem 2
    - illuminate/container is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/container v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - illuminate/contracts is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/contracts v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - illuminate/events is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/events v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.   
  Problem 5
    - illuminate/filesystem is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/filesystem v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - illuminate/support is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/support v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - illuminate/view is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/view v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - illuminate/console is locked to version v5.6.39 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - illuminate/console v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - paragonie/random_compat is locked to version v9.99.99 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - illuminate/config v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - roots/sage-lib 9.0.9 requires illuminate/config ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/config[v5.6.39].
    - roots/sage-lib is locked to version 9.0.9 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Comment: Apparently the library does not support PHP8. It hasn't been updated in 2 years, so may be abandoned.

Comment: Oke, so I should downgrade to an older PHP version?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible it won't work with PHP8. However, if you'd like to try, use the flag "--ignore-platform-reqs" on your install.

Answer (score 1):

use the below command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and update your composer.json file PHP version and `platform-check`:

```
"platform-check": false,

"require": {
  "php": ">=8.0.2",
  "roots/acorn": "^2.0"
}
```